# How do I actually get a field value using field_view_value()?

Tags: 7, entities

I simply want to get the value of a field and have been told I should use [field_view_value](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_view_value/7.x).

To this affect I have created:

```
$field_text_items = field_get_items('node', $node_context->data, 'field_text');

$field_text_items_value = field_view_value('node', $node_context->data, 'field_text', $field_text_items[0]['value']);
```

But running `dpm($field_text_items_value);` just returns an array with:

```
#markup (String, 1 characters ) h
#access (Boolean) TRUE
```

I'm assuming, because my field's value begins with a 'h', the `#markup` is only returning the first character for some reason.

Running `dpm($field_fcc_text_items[0]['value']);` returns the correct result so I know thing field is fine.

I've looked at the documentation linked above, but to be honest a lot of it doesnt make sense.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction here?

Thanks

As a side question, why is `field_view_value()` preferable to just using something like `$field_text_items[0]['value']` anyway?

Answer (score 2):

You may have the field_view_value parameters wrong. Instead of the entity_type-> delta try loading the field first using field_get_items. Use the return value as the second parameter in field_get_items.

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_name');
$output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_name', $field[$delta]);
```

I took that answer from the blog: https://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way